# Build off of Existing Example Simulation

Tags: anylogic

I am taking a M&S class and downloaded the free version of Anylogic.  Can I use one of the examples as a starting point for my class sim and build off of it to configure it a bit differently?  If so, how do I display the palette so that I can add additional inputs or conditions.  Again, I am very new to this!

Comment: Could you please explain exactly what you need? What did you try doing and how it failed... It's hard to help with this level of detail. Maybe add a screenshot.

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. This place works best for you if you ask very specific questions, show exactly what you tried already and where you are stuck. Your question if far too broad and would need a full lecture to tell you all about it. I suggest you read up here to learn how to ask great questions: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask Treat us as very busy colleagues that are happy to help. The more effort you put into your question, the more likely you will get a good, fast reply :)

Comment: Good advice Benjamin, and Emile as well.  I will try more things and get more information before posting!